# Error in pox controller in sdn using python2 and python3 for detectionEntropy

Tags: python, linux, sdn, pox

I am trying to run pox controller using the command
`python2 ./pox.py forwarding.​ l3_detectionEntropy`*emphasized text*

Then I got this error.

`     Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "./pox.py", line 43, in <module>
  from pox.boot import boot
  File "/home/name/pox/pox/boot.py", line 38, in <module>
  import pox.core
  File "/home/name/pox/pox/core.py", line 182, in <module>
  import pox.lib.recoco as recoco
  File "/home/name/pox/pox/lib/recoco/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  from .recoco import *
  File "/home/name/pox/pox/lib/recoco/recoco.py", line 17, in <module>
from queue import PriorityQueue
```

ImportError: No module named queue`

Also I have tried to run it in python3 by converting it into python3 Then i got this error.
`Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/home/shivani/pox/pox/boot.py", line 74, in do_import2
  __import__(name, level=0)
  File "/home/shivani/pox/pox/forwarding/l3_detectionEntropy.py", line 129
  print "dpid port and its packet count: ",  str(event.connection.dpid), 
  str(diction[event.connection.dpid]), str(diction[event.connection.dpid][event.port])
      ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  Could not import module: forwarding.l3_detectionEntropy`
```

How to solve these error??

Answer (score 0):

Adding paranthesis around the print statement should fix the issue.
Python 3 would raise a SyntaxError if we called the print function the Python 2-way without the parentheses.